# Installing Minor Software Updates

Tags: rhel

On an existing `Red Hat Enterprise Linux` server, I need to perform software upgrades on `Java`, `Apache` and `Samba`.

I need to install minor updates for each of the above software.

How can I figure out how they were installed? How would I go about upgrading the software?

**EDIT** I'd like to maintain the `current configuration` of the already mentioned software. Are there any precautions that I need to take when installing the `minor` patches?

Comment: Usually they were installed with yum - `man yum` is a good place to start. Also I highly recommend reading **all** of https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/index.html and as much other RHEL docs as you can get your hands on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the updates for the packages as offered by Red Hat. Installing non-official packages over the distribution-provided ones *will* make your maintenance contract void. And it will probably give other sort of grief.

Answer (score 3):

You can see if a file is part of a rpm package with:

```
rpm -qf $(which java)
```

If it is not part of a RPM package, then it was installed from an archive (tar.gz, zip). Samba and apache can be distributed as source code that you have to compile or as rpm. Java is distributed as rpm or archive.

If the software was installed from rpm, use yum to upgrade them. If it is from source code, then you have to follow the documentation that came with that software.